# Should each individual column have its charset defined?

Tags: mysql

Simple question: when creating database tables I already specify the collation for the entire table, however, individual columns also have a  collation field. Should this be left blank or filled with the same collation as the table (for non-numeric types that is)?

Could anyone shed some light on what this field is for exactly? My suspicion is that it is used for when the column's collation differs from the table's collation, however, I would like a confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Leave it blank and it will use the table's collation. (See [here in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-column.html).)

As for what all this is for, see the manual section [Character Set Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset.html) and, in particular, [Specifying Character Sets and Collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-syntax.html).

Comment: Thanks. And as for the second part of my question, am I correct?

Comment: @Limoncello - Updated my answer (including links to relevant sections of the manual).